# Move all duplicates but one to another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have the following Ms Access DB table structure:

```
SET | in_ID | out_ID | at_version - Fields
=================================
 66 | s321  | 444    | 2020 - What we want to keep
 66 | s321  | 444    | 2020 - Records completely the same
 66 | s321  | 433    | 2020 - in_ID is the same but other fields are different
 61 | s333  | 455    | 2020 -_
 62 | s335  | 455    | 2020 - |_ Unique records in terms of in_ID - we keep those
```

A record is considered to have duplicates if any other record have the same `in_ID`.

Dupe records can be complete dupes or only `in_ID` can match.

I need a query that keeps only one "unique" record (in terms of `in_ID`) in `TableA`, but moves all other "duplicates" to `TableB`.

The resulting table should like the following:

```
SET | in_ID | out_ID | at_version - Fields
=================================
 66 | s321  | 444    | 2020 
 61 | s333  | 455    | 2020 
 62 | s335  | 455    | 2020
```

Comment: for in_ID s321 why you choose the first one( out_id 444) but not the one with with out_id 435? what's the logic there?

Comment: @eshirvana Sorry I do not see a record matching the with in_ID s321 and out_ID 435.
If your question is (just an assumption) why we keep the first record, but disregarding the complete dupe below it - it really does not matter which one we choose.

Comment: @l000p you need to have some sort of criteria to delete the duplicates.  Since you don't seem to have a primary key (or haven't included it in your example) a delete based on the columns you have provided would result in all rows being deleted where there are duplicates.  

you could put a list of duplicated rows in another table but you wouldn't be able to accurately delete the ones in the existing table without some other sort of criteria to make the rows unique.  

What is the end result you want to get to by doing this?

Comment: @Bee_Riii the criteria is very basic - if we have a duplicates - in_ID is the same as in any other record we keep only one of the records no matter which one the rest are moved from TableA (which contains the data) to TableB (which contains the removed dupes from TableA). I have also updated my question to include the end result of the table

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-duplicate-records-with-a-query-3cc805a2-2a13-4439-b0d3-6b23c7d60fbb

Comment: @Bee_Riii that does not do the job as it selects all the duplicates. In our case we need to keep one and discard/move the others.

Comment: Add another column that is an autoincrement, and then join the table to itself on `in_id = in_id and autoinc <=  autoinc`. It means for every in_id, there will be one in_id with th lowest autoinc, and then the next one matches twice, then 3 times etc.. which can then be grouped to give a count. Put all records where count > 1 into the duplicates table.

Comment: Note: you don't need to add an autoinc column if you already have something that increments and is unique,

Comment: @CaiusJard Is there a way to avoid the auto increment field? I do not have a field that is unique nor increments.

Comment: Then add one. The whole idea is that the technique qorks because for any incrementing number there is only a subset of rows twhose number is less. Think about having a table with two columns, a letter and a number: `a 1, a 2, a 3` and you then do `SELECT * FROM t t1 JOIN t t2 ON t1.leter = t2.letter and t1.number <= t2.number`.. You end up with `a1:a1, a2:a1, a2:a2, a3:a1, a3:a2, a3:a3` - there is only one a1:a1 record, then there are two a2:ax and three a3:ax. If you then group and COUNT(*) them it gives a row number - you can keep row number 1, and delete rows numbered > 1

Comment: Alternatively thing about it like this: if you give every row an inc number then you can GROUP BY in_id and get the MIN(autoinc) - that's the row you want to keep, and delete the others. This is actually how Access does a "remove duplicates" operation - it assigns an incrementing unique number (so it can uniquely identify a row to keep and which to delete)